# Do the rules for the "Buying a Magic Item" downtime activity allow a character an opportunity to purchase the item later?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, optional-rules, downtime

I'm DMing using the ["Buying a Magic Item"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#BuyingaMagicItem) downtime activity rules in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 126). Are any rules (or suggested approaches) to allowing my players to purchase one of their discovered magic items at a later date?

For instance, one of the players rolled for a Saddle of the Cavalier but none of the party has a horse. Do the rules allow the player to track down the merchant at a later date to buy the item? Or is this more of a DM's discretionary decision?

Comment: Are horses hard to come by in the game you are running? It seems like it would be easy to buy both the saddle and then a horse to put it on.

Comment: Or buy the saddle and store it somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There is no written rule, but it's at DM discretion.

The section on buying magic items has no direction on what to do if a character rolls a magic item they can't yet use, but it does have this:

> You [the DM/GM] have final say in determining which items are for sale and their final price, no matter what the tables say.

This means you can also decide to put an item on the "backburner" as it were, and allow them to find the same merchant with the same item when they're in a position to use it.